# PHP json_decode does not work with single unpaired surrogate caused by Node 12 well-formed JSON.stringify

Tags: php, node.js, utf-8, surrogate-pairs

Node 12 now uses [Well-formed JSON.stringify](https://v8.dev/features/well-formed-json-stringify) which outputs escape sequences for lone surrogates. PHP is not able to json_decode this when there is a lone surrogate that is escaped.

Take the following code example in Node.

```js
var a = '  ';
JSON.stringify(a.slice(0, 15));

// Node 10 output: 
'"�"';

// Node 12 output:
'"\\ud835"'
```

This response is then sent to a PHP server as JSON and decoded. Which is where the error occurs. 
Node10's output used to work fine with PHP json_decode but it no longer works with Node12's output.

I simplified the NODE->PHP example see below.

```php
<?php
$string = '{"string": "\\ud835"}';
var_dump(json_decode($string, false, 512, JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR | JSON_INVALID_UTF8_IGNORE | JSON_INVALID_UTF8_SUBSTITUTE));

// Output:
Fatal error: Uncaught JsonException: Single unpaired UTF-16 surrogate in unicode escape in phptest.php:36
Stack trace:
#0 phptest.php(36): json_decode('{"string": "\xF0\x9D\x98...', false, 512, 7340032)
#1 {main}
  thrown in phptest.php on line 36
```

I expect the following options `JSON_INVALID_UTF8_IGNORE` or `JSON_INVALID_UTF8_SUBSTITUTE` to work with json_decode in PHP 7.3+ but it does not help at all. `JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR` does actually throw an error to make it easier to debug.

Comment: You should prioritize fixing that bad output from Node 10 over trying to force PHP to accept it. Just because Node10 will happily cut a UTF8 sequence in half doesn't mean it's "well-formed".

Comment: I might not have been clear, but the output above from Node 10 works fine with PHP json_decode. The new change for well formed json introduced in Node 12 does NOT work for lone surrogates that are escaped.

Comment: Neat story. Still corrupt data. Both versions.

Comment: OP  - have you been able to deal with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in Javascript.

Your string in a contains multibyte characters. With a.slice(0, 15) you get 15 Byte, not 15 characters and create a invalid utf-8 string. Multibyte characters may be not mutilated.

Update:

I think the options JSON_INVALID_UTF8_IGNORE and JSON_INVALID_UTF8_SUBSTITUTE are intended for json_encode () and not to sanitize invalid JSON for json_decode ().
The clean solution is to provide a valid JSON on the Javascript page.

The dirty solution is the attempt to correct invalid JSON with PHP:

```
$json = preg_replace_callback(
  '~\\\u[a-d0-9]{4}~iu',
  function($found){
    if(json_decode('"'.$found[0].'"')){
      return $found[0];
    }
    return "";  //or "?"
  },
  $invalidJson
);
```

Comment: yes I understand that, but PHP should still be able to parse this json string by skipping the bad characters or substitute it since I passed those options params > `JSON_INVALID_UTF8_IGNORE | JSON_INVALID_UTF8_SUBSTITUTE`

Comment: careful because it doesn't handle the case where there is an (or more?) additionnal \ before \u.
I suggest modifying the regex to `~(?<!\\\)\\\u[a-d0-9]{4}~iu`

Comment: Also, why a-d instead of a-f ?
I suggest modifying the regex to `~(?<!\\\)\\\u[a-f0-9]{4}~iu`